# Запись в одну строку python

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Есть такой небольшой кусок кода который выводит переменную `k` в виде:

```
hvashchenko
@hvashchenko-pc
```

а мне нужно чтобы переменная была в виде:

```
hvashchenko@hvashchenko-pc
```

Вот код:

```
import subprocess
import socket
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output(["users"])
d = out.decode('utf8')
hostname = socket.gethostname()
k = d +"@"+ hostname
print(k)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно убрать символ конца строки в переменной `d`, например, при помощи функции `rstrip`

```
d = out.decode('utf8').rstrip('\n')
```